# Continue train xgboost specifically on misclassified observations?

Tags: classification, boosting, unbalanced-classes, overfitting, continual-learning

I'm considering integrating the Boosting technique into a basic XGBoost classification model, in which I'd focus on misclassified instances. Assuming I have already used `hyperopt` to build a basic XGBoost model ( let us name it `xgboost_model`), I want to understand if the following approach is sound:

a. Identify and isolate observations where the XGBoost model's predictions are incorrect. For example, in a classification model, if `y_pred` probability is less than 0.1 when `y_true` is 1.

b1. Increase the weight of misclassified observations and randomly sample from the original dataset to generate the next training set, `x_train_2` and `y_train_2`.

b2. Continuously train the existing model using `model = model.fit(x_train_2, y_train_2, xgb_model=xgboost_model.get_booster())`.

In my experiments, I've noticed a slight improvement in the `aucpr` on the validation dataset. Since my dataset is highly imbalanced, I've been using `aucpr` instead of `auc`. However, I'm uncertain if these results are due to luck or if this strategy is theoretically sound. I'm particularly concerned about potential **overfitting**.

Is this a valid concern?

Comment: (+1) AUCPR baseline is dependent on the proportion of positive examples in a dataset. Are we sure we are not accidentally moving the baseline AUCPR and thus perceiving that change as the "slight improvement" reported? That said, and wanting to avoid resampling, have you considered changing the weights to some of the "harder to predict" data instances? What you describe is not "theoretically incomprehensible", to me it seems like a way of doing a rough Adaboost step mid-XGBoost.